# Is it possible to ask questions in sanskrit?

Tags: discussion

I feel rather clumsy asking my questions [usually in along the lines of [this]](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15062/how-common-is-it-to-combine-aupasana-and-vaishvadeva-oblations-in-a-single-homa?noredirect=1#comment37053_15062) in English. Can I type the question in Sanskrit please (while still keeping the tile in English)? People who can answer such questions will doubtless have no problem.

Sanskrit is after all the dominant liturgical language of Hinduism.

Comment: Sanskrit is indeed the dominant liturgical language of Hinduism, but Hinduism.SE is an English-language site, so questions and answers should be written in English.  But it's absolutely fine to give Sanskrit quotes in your questions and answers, as long as they're accompanied by an English translation of the quote.

Comment: Is it possible at all to fix the policy so as to allow Sanskrit in Devanagari on Hinduism se?